# jQuery .live() and .on(): what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to bind a click event to certain elements in jQuery (v1.8.18). I have two elements that match my selector that exist at the time I'm doing the bind, but there's also a third element that will eventually match my selector, but which doesn't get marked up until some point after I've registered the events.

When I just use:

```
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').bind('click', toggleCollapsibleList);
```

...then it correctly binds to the two that exist ahead of time, but obviously not to the third one. When I use:

```
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').live('click', toggleCollapsibleList);
```

...then none of them are getting bound. And when I use:

```
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').on('click', toggleCollapsibleList);
```

...then it behaves the same as .bind(). I have confirmed with the developer tools that all three elements exist in the DOM and match the selector after the page has finished loading. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq] if you haven't already. Additionally, it would be helpful if you'd create a reduced test case on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This'll sound dumb, but we've all forgetten to check it before: Have you confirmed that toggleCollapsibleList *isn't* getting called for the third element (perhaps it's being called, but isn't doing what you expect).

Comment: Also, that second one should work just fine.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Yeah, I set a breakpoint on the first line of that function in the debugger, and the breakpoint was only getting hit for the first two.

Comment: Good, always worth checking.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was introduced in **1.7** thus deprecating `.live()`. The way you're using `.on()` is currently incorrect for if you want it to behave like [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

You effectively want to use `.on()` something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon', toggleCollapsibleList);
```

The following is taken from the jQuery [`.live()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: I just tried `$(document).on('click', '.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon', toggleCollapsibleList);`, but it behaved the same way as .live() did (that is, it didn't bind to any of the elements).

Comment: Please could you create an example of the issue on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/WS5Mx/) using `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// These will attach an event handler for all elements which match the 
// current selector NOW
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').bind('click', toggleCollapsibleList);
// is equivalent to
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').on('click', toggleCollapsibleList);


// These will attach an event handler for all elements which match the 
// current selector NOW AND IN THE FUTURE

// not recommended
$('.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon').live('click', toggleCollapsibleList); 
// is equivalent to
// recommended
$(document).on('click', '.collapsible h2 > .ui-icon', toggleCollapsibleList);
```